# Error when testing against Firebase Emulator 'Expected type 'Pa', but it was: a custom Fa object'

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, cypress, firebase-tools

I'm currently attempting to execute the following test in Cypress.

```
before(async () => {
  testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
    projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID,
    firestore: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8080,
    },
  });
});
describe("Authorized user can write to collection", () => {
  it("Can write to firestore doc", async () => {
    console.log("testEnv", testEnv);

    const alice = testEnv.authenticatedContext("alice", { role: "user" });
    console.log("alice", alice);

    const firestore = alice.firestore();
    console.log("firestore", firestore);

    const testA = await assertSucceeds(
      setDoc(alice.firestore(), "/users/alice"),
      {
        foo: "bar",
      }
    );
    console.log("testA", testA);
  });
});
```

The test fails before the final console.log during the setDoc call. The error is

```
Expected type 'Pa', but it was: a custom Fa object
```

I believe I traced this custom Fa object to the _delegate property on the firestore variable, but I am unclear of how to proceed from here.

- I make sure that the emulators are all running before running `npx cypress open`
- I tried setting the firestore property via the hub and get the same result
- I have also tried passing a 'rules' property to firestore as a string

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can `assertSucceeds()` handle the fact that `setDoc()` is asynchronous?

Comment: I am facing the same issue but my error message looks like this:
`FirebaseError: Expected type 'DocumentReference', but it was: a custom Firestore object` Maybe that helps. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: The documentation of [`setDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#setdoc) tells me that it expects a `DocumentReference`. But the documentation [Test your Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator#rut-v2-common-methods) uses it like in the original question. I am confused. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: I made it work by using an actual document reference: `setDoc(alice.firestore().collection('users').doc('alice'), {foo: "bar"});` Maybe the firebase documentation is not specific enough at this point.

Comment: I am running into the same issue using a different testing framework (vitest). I tried both approaches: the way it is done in the original question, as well as the way Jan proposed. I either get the error message "Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore" or in the second case "Type does not match the expected instance. Did you pass a reference from a different Firestore SDK?"